# Cycles render is too bright

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I cannot seem to create a night time effect in a simple scene. Evee renders the scene as too dark and no matter what I do Cycles render is too bright. [image]

I have tried:
1) Disable all lights
2) Zero emission strength of all emissive materials
3) Disable ambient occlusion
4) The environment strength is 0.1
5) Tried to tweak and lower some settings under Cycles Lightpaths.

Nothing seems to affect the render. Here is the [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eZeFtZVLvi5l_sFL8P5v6ZzZftOIJbn0/view?usp=sharing) in case it is needed

Comment: Darken the world color and reduce light gtrength.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably didn't turn off Ambient Occlusion in the Scene context menu. Do that (and only that) and you get this:

[image]

Also, if you change the background color to black (AFTER turning off Ambient Occlusion in the Scene context menu), the entire scene will be black (which will not happen when it is on). This signals that changing the background color will now affect ambient lighting